# How to add div id url

Tags: url, drupal, redirect

I have a URL which goes to login page. After successful login, I want to redirect to the particular page. For this, I have used below the line.

> http://example.com/user/login?destination=gallery

This URL redirects the user to the gallery page after login. In want gallery I want show recent section after login . So I changed the URL to

> http://example.com/user/login?destination=gallery#recent
>   and
>   http://example.com/user/login?destination=gallery?id=#recent.

Both not taking user to recent section, also #recent id was removed from URL after login.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could find several options using some core capabilities or contributed modules. Check [How to redirect users after login in drupal?](https://www.drupal.org/node/683696). You could also take a code way like implementing [hook_user_login](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_login/7.x) and there make a call to [drupal_goto](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7.x) and things like that.

Answer (score 0):

> Make sure your div #recent is in the same HTML page which opens after
>   login.

on successful login redirect to 
href="http://example.com/user/login?destination=gallery#recent"

For your better understanding here is an illustration.My comment is in same page as you question.We can use it by it's id.You can link to any id by appending it to the end of the url, as an example, here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37453202/how-to-add-div-id-url#37453397) to my comment

Comment: Yes, div #recent belongs to the same HTML page.